# Ethereum address URL

Tags: interfaces, user-experience

Is there a standard or a convention for URLs of Ethereum address?

That is I want clicking `xxx://0x...` to initiate transfer to this account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [EIP67](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67) that proposes

#### Sending ETH

`ethereum:<address>[?from=<sender_address>][?value=<ethamount>][?gas=<suggestedGas>]`

#### Sending ERC20 tokens

`ethereum:<address>[?from=<sender_address>][?value=<ethamount>][?gas=<suggestedGas>][?mode=erc20__transfer]`